# C# regex and dollar sign

Tags: c#, regex, hex

I have created a regex for highlighting certain assembly-styled hex numbers which are like this:

```
$00  
$1400  
$FFFFFF
```

Sometimes they are preceeded with a # as well. So I created this regex as a start:

```
@"\b(\$)[A-Fa-f\d]+\b"
```

When I tried it out, it didn't seem to match anything. However, if I replace the \$ with 0x, it works fine and returns matches for C# style hex-numbers like 0x0F, 0xFF, etc.

Why is this? I have spent a few hours trying to make this regex work but I just can't and have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\b` matches between an alphanumeric character and a non-alphanumeric character - it does not match between `$` and `#`, space, or other characters. You may want to drop it entirely:

```
@"(\$)[A-Fa-f\d]+\b"
```

If you don't want the pattern to match with an alphanumeric character before it, you can add `\B` before it (so `#$00` and `a $00` would match, but `a$00` would not). You can also be more picky, and disallow only certain characters:

```
@"(?<=[\w$])(\$)[A-Fa-f\d]+\b"
```

See also: [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: One extra tip - `\d` in .net matches non-ascii digits (like Arab digits), which is probably not needed. `0-9` would probably be better here.

Comment: You guys are awesome, every time I post a question here I get a correct response within minutes. Thank you for telling me something which I didn't know.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the word boundary `\b`. It matches after the dollar sign. For example this one would work `@"(\$)[A-Fa-f\d]+"`

Answer (score 2):

It would work fine if you remove the `\b` in the start. It then would become

```
@"(\$)[A-Fa-f\d]+\b"
```

`\b` matches the boundary between word character and non-word character, and the `$` here is a non-word character.